# custom class swift setting constraints to superview

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to create a custom UIView that I can add to any view and have it show a red error message like instagram does in the [picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m4Bz.png) I am able to do this programmatically in my view controller but want to create a modular class that I can add it into any view where I want to show an error. My question is how can I add constraints to superview in a custom class?

For example how would I do:

```
    topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0)
    leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0)
    rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0)
    widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: errorLabel.frame.size.height,0)
```

In a custom class so that I don't have to do it in my view controller?  Can I access whatever superView's constraints so that my view is always located at the top?

```
class CustomUIAlertView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Can you give guidance on how to approach this? I feel like I am missing something basic.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to pass the `superview` as parameter to the `init` method.

Something like that:

```
class CustomUIAlertView : UIView {
    weak var parent:UIView
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    required init(frame:CGRect, superview:UIView) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.parent = superview
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Much obliged